# using sockets to chat in web app gives me an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I Tried  to use sockets in asp.net using C#.

The commented line in the client code gives me error.

The server code is running properly.

This is the Client Code which Gives error.

```
   using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
string readData = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



}

protected void Post_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtmsg.Text != "")
    {
        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtmsg.Text + "$");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length); 
        // This line gives error Saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        serverStream.Flush();
    }


}
protected void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSub.Text != "")
    {
        try
        {
            readData = "Conected to Chat Server ...";
            msg();
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtSub.Text + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
            ctThread.Start();

        }
        catch
        {
            //Disconnect();
        }
    }
}

private void getMessage()
{
    while (true)
    {
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        int buffSize = 0;
        byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
        buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
        string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
        readData = "" + returndata;
        msg();
    }
}

private void msg()
{
    //if (this.InvokeRequired)
    //    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
    //else
    txtget.Text = txtget.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData;
} 
}
```

Comment: What error did you get? Additionally: having a long running action in the page life cycle doesn't make sense. Threads in an ASP.NET page are usually considered bad pratice and won't really do what you want them to do. Remember: this is not code running forever like a windows application. It is usually stopped as soon as the page rendering was done (keyword page lifecycle for asp.net)

Comment: You may want to accept some answers to the previous questions you asked

Answer (score 0):

Your `serverSteam` object isn't being properly initialised and therefore causes an object error when you try to reference it.

You need to create a new NetworkSteam with a Socket object, and ensure that your Socket object is connected:

```
Socket my_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
..
// connect socket and any other operations
..
NetworkStream my_network_stream = new NetworkStream(my_socket);
```